# Change font & font-size for different languages without the html lang tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

So, I have some posts that use two different languages (English & Korean) in lines: something like:

> This is an example (예시).

and I switch back and forth between the two languages quite frequently.

I want to use different fonts with different font sizes as well.

I would usually do this by specifying different blocks of CSS using `lang(en)` and `lang(ko)`, but this becomes annoying, since this would require writing my HTML content lines like:

```
<p lang="en">This is an example (<span lang="ko">예시</span>)</p>
```

I want to minimize having to specify HTML stuff, since I mix the two languages frequently and plan on writing my posts using Markdown.

I know that, within CSS `font-family`, if a specific language isn't provided by the high-priority font set, it automatically looks for the next, so I can do something like:

```
body { font-family: "Some Only English Font", "Some Korean Font" }
```

which will do the trick for changing the font, if the first font does not support Korean. Is there maybe some way I can utilize this property to change the font sizes for the different languages?

Any other method to do this, of course, will be helpful.

(Is it perhaps possible to use JS to detect the font, and change the font-size only if it uses the "Some Korean Font"?)

Answer (score 2):

I think that to look for a JS method to detect the language (despite being complicated) will add an unnecessary overhead to your pages: I would fix it beforehand.

Why don't you write your post in a text editor like this?

> This is an example (@@@예시@@).

Then just replace @@@ with `<span lang="ko">` and @@ with `</span>` and start to work normally with Markdown.

Depending of your content, maybe you can find a faster combination of characters to identify the Korean text:

> This is an example (%%예시%).

Choose whatever that is unique and fast to type.

You can do it manually (search and replace) if you write like one post per week or through an automatic script if you write very often. Actually, you could create a task that triggers the script when a file in certain directory changes.

Comment: Sensible solution, parsing each line of text would certainly add unnecessary overhead when rendering the page.

Comment: @MasterYoda. I really think so. And after parsing there will be one (best case) huge DOM update. Also, I don't like altering semantics with JS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 got an attribute named

> data

```
<tagHTML id="myid" data-var_name="value" data-lang="en" ...>
```

you can add a lot of **data-lang="en"** ... the result is you got a **dataset** and you can got a **list as an array** and access simply like this :

```
var article = document.getElementById('myid');

article.dataset.var_name// "value"
article.dataset.lang // "en"
..
```

Comment: Yeah, but this will still require explicitly stating the language variable within the content, right? I was looking for a way to do that automatically without having to specify it.

Comment: you can specify what you want just replace getElementById and using querySelector to target a style for one or queryselectorAll for many in the same time as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, I'd recommend setting the Korean text and adding your font-family font-size spans in a pre-processor method called in $

like,

```
$(function() {
  detectKoreanAndAddSpans();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect font on a letter-by-letter (or at least word-by-word) basis though? I am switching back and forth between the languages within a line/sentence.

Comment: I'm suggesting that when you detect Korean characters, you add spans to set the font-family and font-size programmatically. I am not suggesting that you search for specific fonts

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, but I was wondering how to go about the detection part (without having to detect element or its `lang` variable set manually).)

Comment: @SanhaCheong best way to do might be to create a regular expression like [a-zA-Z]+ but with your Korean characters. Then run `matches` on all elements recursively or on the document text and then calculate the element from the offset. You can actually do something like `element.innerHTML = nonKoreanPart + "<span class=..." + KoreanPart + " </span>" + endingNonKoreanPart`